# C# Multi-Threading on tables' columns performance issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I am currently having an issue with getting the performance benefit using C# Threads. What I am currently doing here is encrypting the entire contents of selected columns in a tabular file (.csv). The program is used for generally large files, whose size may reach up to terabytes in size, with millions of rows and numerous columns.

In order to achieve optimal performance, I planned to create and run the processing algorithm in separate threads for each column. I believe the sheer amount of computation needed for each column warrants a thread each. Or at least it was true when I was doing similar projects using **C++ threads**.

Now, for some reason, the code snippet below **DOES NOT** produce any speed-up what so ever. In fact, the time taken compared to single thread sequential processing differs in only a few seconds **SLOWER**. It is roughly the same result whether I'm processing only 1 column, 4 columns, or 128 columns simultaneously.

```
// NOTE:
// m_TableData is of type |--Dictionary<int, List<string>>--|
// Key   == Column Number
// Value == Column Contents

List<Thread> Threads = new List<Thread>();

// encrypt data in selected columns
foreach (var KeyPair in m_TableData)
{
  Threads.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
  {
    // Process each row element
    // NOTE: ColSize is usually huge (>10,000)
    int ColSize = KeyPair.Value.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < ColSize; ++i)
    {
      m_TableData[KeyPair.Key][i] = ProcessingAlgorithm(m_TableData[KeyPair.Key][i]);
    }
  })));
  Threads.Last().Start();
}

foreach (Thread th in Threads)
  th.Join();
```

In hopes of trying to prevent False Sharing and/or better cache performance I have even tried splitting up the rows into batches of 500, 1000, 10000, etc, but to no avail. I have even tried the **System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach** function, and it also seems to give the same results. The lack of performance improvement has me really scratching my head.

Any professional/experienced parallel-processing programmers over here? I greatly appreciate any and all feedback and criticism on my code and issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is the encryption IO or memory based operation ? Invoking lots of threads bound to make system / processing slow. In `Parallel.For` supply Parallel Options with max degree of parallelism, which is same Environment processor count. I would prefer to convert this into `Async-Await` call, which does IO very efficiently, for which threads are not required.

Comment: The **ProcessingAlgorithm** function is purely a memory based operation. In the function, only local variables are instantiated to modify the input string, therefore there should not be any memory sharing or what so ever.

Comment: Can you check what takes more time `In memory processing` or `File IO`

Comment: Is the result of this code correct and consistent with the result of sequential processing?

Comment: I have profiled my entire program, and the main chunk of time that is required is in this very loop that i posted. reading/writing the table data ranges around maybe a few seconds. This loop however, may take up to a minutes, which is the main motivation for me trying to multi thread it.

Comment: @fofik Yes, the results are correct and as expected. However, the speed-up is most definitely not. The process of encrypting the data is 100% parallel, with no data dependencies.

Comment: You mean In memory encryption takes maximum time, how many are th total threads you are invoking as part of for loop, how many keypair are there in the m_TableData, that is urely clogging the system, by generating way too many threads

Comment: I was suspecting that, which was why I also attempted to use the `Parallel.ForEach` function, as well as trying 4 columns at a time. This should only create 4 threads, as my system only has that. The results are still the same.

Comment: What is the ProcessingAlgorithm method duration and do you use locking inside it?

Comment: It is a simple Substitution Encryption algorithm with no locks or any complex mechanisms inside it, only local variables. It is fairly simple string manipulation algorithm which completes almost instantly, which is why I batched an entire column worth of data to be run per thread.

Comment: I prepered some test data and tried something like yours and according to my test if the job done in that method is too simple threading overhead is much more than the benefits. If I process more records on each thread or increase the ProcessingAlgorithm's duration threading gives better times.

Comment: While the algorithm itself may be fairly simple, it is the sheer number of iterations (>10,000) per column that made me assume that multi threading was beneficial. I mean... if the overall running time for a single thread is a few minutes, shouldn't there be more than enough work for multiple threads? After all, it's not like I'm performing a single addition instruction per loop.

Comment: If I am using 10000 columns and fast processing method results are consistent with yours. If I add more rows multi threaded version takes more and more time than single threaded one. When I add >50000 columns multithreaded version gains some advantage on my tests. So I believe it is because of the context switching overhead. In addition how many rows do you have? Above code may create too many threads unline Parallel library. Besides from that I am out of ideas :(

Comment: may be the time is not spend in ProcessingAlgorithm. more thread create, more time spend  for thread context switch. load the large file into a dictionary is high cost. you can use streamreader to process the file

Comment: The files that I am processing may have up to millions of rows, and thousands of columns. But you are right, I may be creating too many threads that way, and will be changing to a `Parallel.ForEach` loop. However, even with only 4 columns, which equates to 4 threads, with a million rows, I still have the same performance situation. Currently I am reworking into another method going along the lines of `Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(InputFile), line => {/* Do stuff for each line */})`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't your biggest performance issue - something else is going on here (really need to see what your ProcessingAlgorithm is doing) - but you can eliminate 2 dictionary lookups in your loop by replacing:

```
m_TableData[KeyPair.Key]
```

with

```
KeyPair.Value
```

So you end up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ColSize; ++i)
{
    KeyPair.Value[i] = ProcessingAlgorithm(KeyPair.Value[i]);
}
```

(I'd probably actually assign the list to a local variable instead of using the KeyPair)